# Can a file browser, with file opening and previewing disabled, be safe from malware which run when viewed in explorer?

Tags: java, security, explorer, malware, computer-forensics

I am making a custom file explorer in java. I came to know of this worm which starts executing when the file icon is viewed in file explorer. I believe, this could be possible only if it is loaded into memory somehow by something like reading of metadata (Please correct me if i am wrong). I have heard java is a 'safe' language but just wanted to know how much safe it is.

I am using the following imports in my program :

```
java.io.File;

java.net.URL;

java.nio.file.Path;

javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
```

I use `fileSystemView.getFiles()` to get files list and simply display an icon by checking the file extension.Files are not preveiwed also.

So if i disable opening of a file by clicking on its icon in my file browser, then is there any way that some malware can run when my file explorer program displays the contents of an infected pendrive?

Can this be achieved by other programming languages also?

Comment: Have you references on that *worm*? It is hard to say whether a solution protects from a thread without knowing what the threat is...

Comment: I am  not focusing on the single threat mentioned above but for your info you can read more about this worm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet)

Answer (score 2):

There are several aspects to you question here.

First of all, about the danger of accidentally reading/executing files by clicking them in your application: I think it's a bit difficult to answer that without actually seeing the code you're running. I can't see any obvious threat based on your description, but then again, I don't know exactly what your Java Runtime will do for you when you mark a file, read the directory it is in, and read the file itself - if there's no "magic" happening behind the scenes there, there might not be a problem. If Java does any kind of reading/parsing/whatever with a file in order to register and list it though, it's hard to tell.

From the [documentation for Class FileSystemView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getDefaultDirectory())

> Since the JDK1.1 File API doesn't allow access to such information as root partitions, file type information, or hidden file bits, this class is designed to intuit as much OS-specific file system information as possible.

I'm not really sure exactly what this even means, but I take it as an indicator that *something* is going on behind the scenes when accessing files. Perhaps someone with more in-depth knowledge can add to this.

Now as for using this to analyze potentially infected thumb drives: **Be very careful**.

When you connect something to your USB, it can do "stuff"(*) automatically as soon as it is connected. This will likely happen long before you've even started your Java app, so it won't really matter how safely you code it.

There are ways to restrict access to USB, and such auto-run behavior. You should at least be aware and look into this, and make sure you have an updated and working security scanner of some kind before inserting anything suspicious into your PC.

---

(*) *There are even examples where USB devices can steal info from locked computers by providing a (fake or real?) network connection, and then listening in to and manipulating the automatic connections computers typically do continually in the background.*

Comment: But will this happen if all autorun features are disabled ?

Comment: If you can be confident that you have disabled all of them, then no, obviously not; as for what Java might do, I simply do not know enough, neither about your app, nor about how the library you are using works. To be on the safe side though, I would personally prefer to use a completely separate machine for this if possible; One you can wipe both before and after your investigations.